# Determining if polygon falls within another polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, analysis, within

How can I determine if a certain polygon falls within another separate polygon using QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please decide which of the GIS products mentioned you want to ask about.  By asking about more than one you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour]. You should then describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the Spatial Query tool from the Vector menu.

[image]

Enter your source layer & reference/ intersect layer, and specify "within" as the criterion. If you want to only run the query using selected features of either layer, select these before running the query.

[image]

If you wish, you can then use the button shown below to create a new layer from the resulting selection.

[image]

The new layer is then added to the table of contents window. You can then right click on the layer name and "save as" if desired.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add your polygon layers and then go to Vector>Research Tools>Select By Location.  Set your parameters accordingly and make sure to check the 'Within' box for the Geometric predicate, and run it.