# Determine if a point lies within a polygon/shape in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv, count

I am working with a dataset that records violence cases (CSV file). All violence cases are geocoded to a latitude/longitude address so that they can be coordinated to any given shapes/polygons.

What would be the best method to determine whether a point (violence cases) lies within a polygon? I have a raster layer that may contains hundreds of polygons, and would like to generate boolean result (0/1) or dummy variables for each polygon.

Comment: Did I correctly understand your question: You want to determine whether a point (a vector) is within a polygon (a rater), is not it? Can you please clarify this info for us.

Comment: Hi Taras. Yes. I am trying to determine whether a point is in a polygon. The points come from a csv data set and polygons come from a multipolygon layer. I believe both two layers are vector though.

Comment: You can start with basics [1]["Join attributes by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location) [2]Field Calculator with the [`overlay_within()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-within) function, [3]SAGA's ["Add polygon attributes to points"](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.7/shapes_points_10.html) module in the Processing Toolbox, or [4]https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86444/spatially-joining-polygon-fields-onto-point-layer-in-qgis, or

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is totally possible by using the Vector menu, then navigating to the Spatial Query tool. Select within from the dropbox menu that appears on the tool and you're ready to go. [This topic might also help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/258221/103942).

**But!**

You said that you have a **raster** of many polygons. You must polygonize them using the [polygonize tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/polygonize.html) first.

Comment: Hi Ash. I am sorry - I am working with vectors of many polygons. Does that mean I don't have to polygonize them first?

Comment: If your two inputs are both vectors, you don't need to polygonize anything. Good luck.